# Signed a scam contract and lost some $$$

Tags: solidity, scam

So.. I signed a bad contract :-(

Trusted a friend who's account was hacked. Used a burner wallet so not too much harm done. However, Im not sure if Im still at risk using the wallet, or if it was a one time only transfer.

Anyone here clever enough to read the contract and tell me?
This contract: 0xd13b093eafa3878de27183388fea7d0d2b0abf9e (on ethereum)

https://etherscan.io/address/0xd13b093eafa3878de27183388fea7d0d2b0abf9e#code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't execute contracts that you don't understand. The contract doesn't do anything interesting. It accepts anyone deposit, and only allows the owner to withdraw its balance. It is an old solidity version, so its bytecode could have a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your wallet is safe.
But it would be careless to trust me; better to be safe and forget about that wallet. If anything is left there, move those funds to another wallet.